# MySQL: Name primary key in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, mysql

How do I set the name of a primary key when creating a table?

For example here I'm trying to create a primary key with the name 'id', but this is invalid SQL. Can you tell me the correct way to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_test`
(
    `default_test`.`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY `id`,
    `default_test`.`name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL
)
```

### Clarification

I'd like to specify the name of the primary key - rather than the default name of "PRIMARY" I'd like it to be called "id" or perhaps "primary_id", so if I were to later run SHOW INDEXES FROM default_test, the Key_name will be something I have specified.

Comment: To clarify: I'd like to specify the name of the primary key - rather than the default name of "PRIMARY" I'd like it to be called "id" or perhaps "primary_id", so if I were to later run SHOW INDEXES FROM default_test, the Key_name will be something I have specified.

Comment: Ah - I've just discovered - correct me if I'm wrong - that the name of the primary key *must* be "PRIMARY" ...

Comment: Yes. The name of the primary key MUST be "PRIMARY" according to MySQL documentation. See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303798/mysql-name-primary-key-in-create-table-statement/3303980#3303980) with link.

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively and more widely supported:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_test` (
 `default_test`.`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `default_test`.`name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

#### UPDATE

Based on the clarification, you could replace the last definition above with the following if you are to specify the index name:

```
CONSTRAINT `pk_id` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - not quite what I was after though, I've added a bit of clarification

Answer (score 5):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

> [...] In MySQL, the name of a PRIMARY KEY is PRIMARY. [...]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_test` (
    `default_test`.`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `default_test`.`name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't specify the column name when you specify the primary key column name directly inline with the column definition, so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_test` ( 
 `default_test`.`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY  , 
 `default_test`.`name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL 
 );
```

Alternativly you could do:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_test` ( 
   `default_test`.`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `default_test`.`name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY `default_test_id_pkey` (`id`)
   );
```

Comment: I just ran this, followed by `SHOW INDEXES FROM default_test`. The `Key_name` is "PRIMARY". It doesn't look like the name "default_test_id_pkey" was retained.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the column name again, because you already specified it as part of the current field definition - just say `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_test` (
    `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Alternatively, you can specify it separately later:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_test` (
    `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)
```