# MySql - alias for index name ( PRIMARY )

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to setup an alias for indexes/primary keys?  In other words, MySql has my primary key named "PRIMARY", and I want to name it something else, also, to make it compatible with my software.  I know primary keys have to be named "PRIMARY" ( see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303798/mysql-name-primary-key-in-create-table-statement/3303980#3303980) for the discussion ).  So I figured, if there was a way to make an alias to the primary key, that would solve my problem.

NOTE:  I am not talking about the column name, but the actual name of the index, as would appear in the "Key_name" column when you run the command "show indexes from " command.

2/29/2015 Edit in response to RandomSeed comment:
The PRIMARY KEY column is, say, ithkey.  In SQLServer, the index name is "ITHKEY", so our code was using "ITHKEY" as the index hint.  But, of course, that won't work with my current MySql setup because the index/primary key for ithkey is named "PRIMARY", not "ITHKEY".  I could, I suppose, change my code to reference "PRIMARY" in the index hints, was just trying to avoid that.

Comment: Don't use the `primary key` option, just create a unique index on that column and give it the name you want.

Comment: No, you can't give your primary key constraint a different name than `PRIMARY` in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a functional perspective (as far as MySQL is concerned), the `PRIMARY` key is just a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` constraint<sup>*</sup>.

Therefore you could replace the `PRIMAY KEY` with a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` index that you can name as you see fit.

If the `PRIMARY KEY` is also required by your application (or if the idea of a table without a primary key makes you sick), you can keep both keys on the table, which doubles the corresponding overhead, both in terms of CPU time and storage space (so this is a bad idea).

There is no such thing as an index alias with MySQL.

---

<sup>*</sup> *If you do not define a `PRIMARY KEY` for your table, MySQL locates the first `UNIQUE` index where all the key columns are `NOT NULL` and InnoDB uses it as the clustered index ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html)).*

Comment: I am sure it is possible to easily configure or alter your application so that it can deal with a primary key (which could be regarded as the most fundamental feature of a RDBMS). You may want to share this problem with us, there *must* be a better solution.

Comment: So, basically, I could first add the "UNIQUE NOT NULL" index, then remove the primary index.  Since I now I have a "UNIQUE NOT NULL" index, it should let me remove the primary index.  Kind of new to MySql, so just making sure I understand.  Thanks.

Comment: A primary key is never required, so you should be able to drop it even without the `UNIQUE` key. (note: a table without a primary key is considered bad practice, but we are making the deliberate choice to replace it with an equivalent constraint in order to work around an external issue)